# How to covert audio file to base64 using plugins for ionic angular project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, plugins, base64

I'm trying to take audio recordings taken from the media capture ionic plugin and convert the file into a base64 string. I've attached code that works for Android but will not work for IOS or Microsoft.

```
public captureAudio(name: string, notes: string): void {

    this.mediaCapture.captureAudio().then(res => {
        var filePath = res[0].fullPath;

        this.getBase64StringByFilePath(filePath)
            .then((res) => {
                var base64Only = res.slice(34);
                //do something with base64 string
            });
    });
}

public getBase64StringByFilePath(fileURL: string): Promise<string> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.base64.encodeFile(fileURL).then((base64File: string) => {
            resolve(base64File);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    })
}
```

I've noticed that in the base64 conversion plugin that I'm using it states:

"Plugin to get base64 encoding of any IMAGE, Base64 can be retrieved for any file for android, however for iOS images only supported"

Is there any other option for doing this? We've looked into the file plugin below as well but had trouble sending it the exact file path it wanted (it would either return nothing or return an error). We also attempted a more native javascript solution using getUserMedia but that also does not work on IOS due to security.

Plugins used:

- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture
- https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64

Answer (score 3):

THIS FUNCTION HAS BEEN GRABBED FROM AN ONLINE TUTORIAL [https://medium.com/@JordanBenge/ionic-converting-video-to-base64-a95158de3b2a]

Reads the fileURI, uses FileReader() to encode it to base64, and then we have to fix it.
@param aAudioRecording Video file source (URI) of the captured video

```
    private async convertAudioToBase64(aAudioRecording): Promise<{}> {
        return new Promise(async resolve => {
            let lAudioSource: any = await this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(aAudioRecording);

            lAudioSource.file(resFile => {
                let lReader = new FileReader();
                lReader.readAsDataURL(resFile);
                lReader.onloadend = async (evt: any) => {
                    let lEncodingType: string;

                    if (this.dataProvider.getPlatform() == "ios") {
                        lEncodingType = "data:audio/mp3;base64,";
                    } else {
                        lEncodingType = "data:audio/x-m4a;base64,";
                    }

                    /*
                     * File reader provides us with an incorrectly encoded base64 string.
                     * So we have to fix it, in order to upload it correctly.
                     */
                    let lOriginalBase64 = evt.target.result.split(",")[1]; // Remove the "data:video..." string.
                    let lDecodedBase64 = atob(lOriginalBase64); // Decode the incorrectly encoded base64 string.
                    let lEncodedBase64 = btoa(lDecodedBase64); // re-encode the base64 string (correctly).
                    let lNewBase64 = lEncodingType + lEncodedBase64; // Add the encodingType to the string.

                    resolve(lNewBase64);
                };
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: I got this code to build and it made it through to the lReader.readAsDataURL(), but the .onloadend event for it never triggers, any clue as to what would cause that? I added a .onerror event handler but no errors, just nothing.

The code found the file, just readAsDataURL not doing anything.

Comment: Have you tried using other function linked to the FileReader like the .onload to see if the FileReader initializes

Comment: Interesting, I just tried and the debugger didn't trigger for onload either. So, at this point my debuggers for onload, onloadend, and onerror aren't being hit. The only change I've made from your original code in reference to the reader is I moved the events above the .readAsDataURL just because I saw that people often have it that way, but it doesn't work no matter the order.